# Dart/Flutter Generics: type '(SearchFilterItemModel<DateTime>) => String' is not a subtype of type '(SearchFilterItemModel<dynamic>) => String'

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

I have defined models for my search filter items like below:

```
typedef OnFilterButtonPressed<T> = String Function(SearchFilterItemModel<T> searchFilterItem);

class SearchFilterItemModel<T> {
  final String id, name;
  final OnFilterButtonPressed<T> onPressed;

  SearchFilterItemModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.onPressed,
  });
}
```

Then I've defined a list of filter items.

```
List<SearchFilterItemModel> searchFilterItems = [
  SearchFilterItemModel<DateTime>(
    id: "filter_id_date",
    name: "Date",
    onPressed: (SearchFilterItemModel<DateTime> item) {
      return item.id;
    },
  ),
  SearchFilterItemModel<String>(
    id: "filter_id_cost",
    name: "Cost",
    onPressed: (SearchFilterItemModel<String> item) {
      return item.id;
    },
  ),
];
```

I have passed the search filter item as the `onPressed` function argument because I need to access the current model that the `onPressed` function is currently in. You can see, I've used the item id in the `onPressed` function block.

now, I've defined my sample main function like this:

```
void main() {
  print(searchFilterItems.map<String>((SearchFilterItemModel filterItem) {
    return filterItem.onPressed(filterItem);
  }));
}
```

It throws the following error:

> Unhandled exception:
> type '(SearchFilterItemModel<DateTime>) => String' is not a subtype of type '(SearchFilterItemModel<dynamic>) => String'

The error is thrown at the `return filterItem.onPressed(filterItem);` line in the main function.

Questions:

1. Why it can't cast dynamic type to String type?
2. How can I modify my code to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the type of your function onPressed

```
List<SearchFilterItemModel> searchFilterItems = [
  SearchFilterItemModel<DateTime>(
    id: "filter_id_date",
    name: "Date",
    onPressed: (SearchFilterItemModel item) {
      return item.id;
    },
  ),
  SearchFilterItemModel<String>(
    id: "filter_id_cost",
    name: "Cost",
    onPressed: (SearchFilterItemModel item) {
      return item.id;
    },
  ),
];
```

And why do you use a function returning a field of the same object? It's strange.

Wouldn't this do the trick ?

```
get onPressed => id
```

If you need to know the type, you can do this on onPressed

```
 print(searchFilterItems.map<String>((SearchFilterItemModel filterItem) {
      switch(filterItem){
        case SearchFilterItemModel<String>():
          return "It's string ${filterItem.id}";
        case SearchFilterItemModel<DateTime>():
          return "It's datetime ${filterItem.id}";
      }
      return filterItem.onPressed(filterItem);
    }));
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! It works! Can you explain how and why does it work?

Comment: There was a mismatch in your lambda expression on ".map<String>" with was accepting dynamic (without specific typing) and received String or DateTime.
The function "onPressed" doesn't really need to know this type as it's only return the id.

Comment: What if it needs to work with the DateTime or String? Suppose the filter items also have the filter value, like DateTime value or String value. If I need to work with that value in the onPressed, then should I just typecast it? Or is there better way?

Comment: Btw, `onPressed: () => id` shows compiler error that id not found.

Comment: The onPressed could be a get of your class "get onPressed => id;"

Comment: I update my response to take type in account.

Comment: Thanks :D I've marked your answer as accepted. It was really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Give your SearchFilterItemModel a String Type:

```
  print(searchFilterItems.map<String>((SearchFilterItemModel<String> filterItem) {
    return filterItem.onPressed(filterItem);
```

Comment: It shows compiler error: `The argument type 'String Function(SearchFilterItemModel<String>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String Function(SearchFilterItemModel<dynamic>)'`

Also, The searchFIlterItems list also holds DateTime type filter items. So giving `<String>` doesn't actually solves it.